# Installation for ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to ionic framework. I need help for development with ionic. Please suggest me the necessary software to be installed on local computer for developing ionic app. I also need the software for emulating the app on AVD. And deploying the app on mobile.

Comment: Try to hit Google first before posting a question. Google won't kill your cat.

Answer (score 1):

All the questions you are asking, and more, are answered [on ionic framework getting started page](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/).

If you have a problem with a specific step, you should ask a specific question about it.

Comment: NodeJs, Cordova, app, Android SDK is installed. I've developed my web pages on ionic. I can run the web app on my browser. I need help for what to be installed for ADT (emulator), and what is required for building and publishing the app.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow by the way, please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). So it seems to me that your first *question* has been amswered. Please mark it as answered if that's the case and ask another one about the  **specific problem you encountered during ADT installation**.

Answer (score 0):

Next time please first start with searching by yourself but anyways:

Install [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Install Ionic with [Ionic CLI](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/installation/):

`npm install -g ionic cordova`

then start your Ionic Projekt with

`ionic serve`

And to test your App on AVD use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/).

Or just use Ionics [DevApp for Android & iOS.](https://ionicframework.com/docs/appflow/devapp/)

Or  publish your App as APK or IPA like explained [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/)